# Fast grep / grep for line number only?

Tags: linux, search, grep

I am looking for some help with grep, or grep like tools. This includes but not limited to grep, egrep, awk, sed, or what ever other tool that is used for searching for matches. But i will just call it grep for the rest of the question.

I am looking for the fast way to grep a file for a match, and i am also looking for the fastest way to grep a file for a match and to only return the line number its on not the rest of the matched line. I dont mind if the syntax is complex as long as its fast, I am going to be using it in a program complexity is not the issue.

I also need this method to work if I need to regex for a pattern so i can also search for a range. So if i need to search for all numbers less than 10 if the commmand supports it by default of or if it needs to be some regex i am just looking for the fastest method that i can find.

thank you.

Edit

The files i am working with will be very large, my test file is 1.9gb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think KingsIndian is on target with the `-m` option to grep, but if speed is your main goal, `cut` may be faster than `awk` for this particular usage.  try:

```
grep -n -m 1 regex file | cut -d: -f1
```

the `-d:` argument tells cut to use a colon as a field seperator, while the `-f1` argument tells it to only output the first field.

Comment: This worked just like the other ones but did operate a little bit faster on average a few hundred milliseconds. I am guessing if i needed to skip a few I would do grep -n -m 10 regex file | tail -5 | cut -d: -f1

Comment: When using cut, how would you specify a tab as a separator?

Comment: cut uses tab as a separator by default, so just remove the -d:

Answer (score 3):

To stop after the first match:

```
grep -n -m 1 str file | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

You can change the argument value of `m` to a different value to stop after that many matches. The `awk` part is to capure only the line number.

To stop after 5 matches:

```
grep -n -m 5 str file | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

**Edit:**
You can use `tail` for that. For example, to skip first 5 matches and print the next 7: `grep -n -m 12 str file| tail -7 | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Comment: the -m is is pretty cool do you know if there is a way to skip the first few results and then print the next 5 and quit. it is something i am going to need in this project but also just working on outputing everything for the time being.

Comment: that is really cool a I never thought about it that way. Do you know if there is anything faster than awk at what we are asking it to do, or is it faster to just return the grep is -no than to force awk to loop though the result set.

Comment: @WojonsTech grep is pretty efficient in matching than most tools and also it's limited to the first `m` matches. Only those limited set of matches from grep is passed to awk. So it should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is fast, but this seems to work:

```
nl -b a "<filename>" | grep "<phrase>" | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: this works, but i know that instead of using nl you can ue grep -n to get the output with the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do pattern matching using `GNU awk` and simply print out the line numbers:

```
awk '/regex/ { print NR }' file.txt
```

Assuming values are space separated, you can find the line numbers if lines contain numbers less than 10:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i <= 10) print NR }' file.txt
```

However, this will print the line number of each occurrence of a number less than 10. I believe you may find this undesirable. Therefore to remove multiple duplicate line numbers for each match, you can use an array:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i <= 10) array[NR]++ } END { for (i in array) print i }' file.txt
```

If you require sorted output, pipe to `sort -n`. If you prefer a more elegant solution (i.e. with no piping):

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i <= 10) array[NR]++ } END { for (j in array) sorted[k++]=j+0; n = asort(sorted); for (j=1; j<=n; j++) print sorted[j] }' file.txt
```

**EDIT:**

In any of the last three `awk` commands above, simply change `if ($i <= 10)` to `if ($i >= 11 && $i <= 20)` to show results 11 to 20 inclusive.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but seems to be the programic way to solve it using awk

Comment: @WojonsTech: Please update your question with _exactly_ what you want to do. From what I understand, you want to search for some regex and print out the line number and or the matching line. Perhaps I wasn't clear about the latter. In this instance try: `awk '/regex/ { print NR, $0 }' file.txt`. HTH.

Comment: I also was looking for the least system hevery way to use it. I have seen stuff where people use grep and cut and it works pretty fast over all not sure how awk stacks up but i did see that it worked, but is looking the best way to limit the results?

Comment: @WojonsTech: what do you mean "is looking the best way to limit the results"?

Comment: when you work with mysql you can do skip and limit in the LIMIT cluase . there for i want 10 results after the first 10. so shows results 11-20

Answer (score 1):

i just made some tests with a nonforking sed call and was not lucky, but for reference here the numbers with a 1 Gigabyte textfile, where my $PATTERN is part of the very last line:

(spoiler: grep is more than 5 times faster on this operation, awk is slowest)

```
user@box:~$ ls -lh /dev/shm/test 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 979M Jul  8 09:50 /dev/shm/test
```

```
user@box:~$ sed --version | head -n1
GNU sed-Version 4.2.1
user@box:~$ time sed -n "/$PATTERN/{=;q}" /dev/shm/test
206558

real    0m6.835s
user    0m6.160s
sys 0m0.648s
```

```
user@box:~$ grep -V | head -n1
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
user@box:~$ time grep -n -m 1 "$PATTERN" /dev/shm/test | cut -d: -f1
206558

real    0m1.337s
user    0m0.592s
sys 0m0.736s
```

```
user@box:~$ awk --version | head -n1
GNU Awk 4.0.1
user@box:~$ time awk "/$PATTERN/ { print NR }" /dev/shm/test
206558

real    0m7.176s
user    0m6.356s
sys 0m0.776s
```